# How to fix problems withe textures of imported model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I downloaded a fbx model from [cgtrader.com](http://cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/unity-digital-human-hs002). The model contains textures, but doesn't look good. First problem is that the textures of the head aren't placed correctly. The second problem is that the top can't be textured and only shows a pink color.
Trying to resolve the second problem, in UV mode I opened the image texture, selected the pink areas and replaced the auto generated grid to texture image, but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In render properties change render engine from eevee to cycles.
Create new material, assign this material to pink place and copy nodes from other texture, then change properties for current nodes.[image]